# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot shutdown/reboot properly

Tags: kernel, shutdown, reboot

I shut down my PC but it stuck at "Reached target shutdown/reboot".

[Stuck when shutdown/reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVb3I.jpg)

Below is the journal log when I run

```
journalctl -b -p err
```

-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-08-06 20:32:59 +07, end at Fri 2020-08-07 23:17:32 +07. --

```
Thg 8 07 23:14:11 Joker kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffa2220091ffff

Thg 8 07 23:14:11 Joker kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode

Thg 8 07 23:14:11 Joker kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page

Thg 8 07 23:14:12 Joker kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000

Thg 8 07 23:14:12 Joker kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110

Thg 8 07 23:14:12 Joker kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110

Thg 8 07 23:16:55 Joker gdm-password][1601]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Thg 8 07 23:17:11 Joker systemd-udevd[466]: INT3450:00: Worker [512] processing SEQNUM=4314 killed

Thg 8 07 23:17:11 Joker systemd-udevd[466]: INT3450:00: Worker [495] processing SEQNUM=4477 killed

Thg 8 07 23:17:11 Joker systemd-udevd[466]: INT3450:00: Worker [512] failed

Thg 8 07 23:17:11 Joker systemd-udevd[466]: INT3450:00: Worker [495] failed
```

I tried to re-install the graphics driver but it still does not work.
[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3buqJ.png)

---

**--- Edit ---**

Command: `free -h`

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2,2Gi        27Gi       131Mi       1,6Gi        28Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

---

Command: `swapon -show`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

---

Command: `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

Command: `sudo lshw -C memory`

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 0808
       date: 05/14/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 44
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-16GTZR
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-16GTZR
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 51
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 52
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 53
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2320000-a2323fff
```

---

Command: `sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

---

Command: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
0808
```

**My PC**

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10500 CPU @ 3.10GHz
MotherBoard: ASUS ROG STRIX B460-F GAMING Rev 1.xx
BIOS version: 0808
Memory: 02 x G-Skill F4-3000C16-16GTZR 16384 MB @ 2666MHz (DIMM DDR4)
Graphics: ASUS TUF GTX 1660 Super-6G GAMING
```

---

**Update**  (2020-08-11)

I have updated NVIDIA to 450.57 and increased swapfile to 4GB but still error.
Command : `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 31%   39C    P8    18W / 125W |    283MiB /  5936MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1018      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1639      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 91MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1841      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              103MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2296      G   ...token=7897069570677155215       32MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3216      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3777      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Command: `journalctl -b -p err`

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-08-06 20:32:59 +07, end at Tue 2020-08-11 21:02:57 +07. --
Thg 8 11 21:01:46 Joker kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffb1084094ffff
Thg 8 11 21:01:46 Joker kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Thg 8 11 21:01:46 Joker kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
Thg 8 11 21:01:47 Joker kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
Thg 8 11 21:01:47 Joker kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
Thg 8 11 21:01:47 Joker kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
Thg 8 11 21:02:38 Joker gdm-password][1535]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I found this [article](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206653). And I have updated kernel to the latest version 5.8 and it's working.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -show` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema I edited my question follow your suggestion. Check, please. Thank you!

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have page fault errors, and Nvidia errors.

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at version 0808.

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia version 440.

There's a newer version available, version 450.57, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

[image]

Direct download is [here](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.57/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run).

**SWAP**

Let's replace a possible bad /swapfile, and enlarge it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 32G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

<strike>Add this line to /etc/fstab...</strike>

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

There's a bug. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206653. Updated the kernel to 5.8 and it's working now.

Comment: I have installed NVIDIA version 450.57 and increased swapfile to 4GB like your suggestion but still error.

Comment: I have just updated my question. Check, please. Thank you!

Comment: @TungNguyen Edit your question and show me screenshots of the `Disks` application SMART Data scrollable window.

Comment: I found this https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206653. And I have updated kernel to the latest version 5.8 and it's working. Thank for your support.